# Google Tag Manager Event Change is Not Triggered on Page Change Nextjs

Tags: next.js, google-tag-manager, vercel, gtmetrix

The event configured in Google Tag Manager is not triggering during page changes in a Next.js application. Unexpected behavior observed when transitioning from Page A to Page B.

Steps to Reproduce:

Open the Next.js application in a supported browser.
Access [URL/Page A] within the application.
Click on a link or use the application's navigation to payment gateway and after successful payment, redirected to page B.
Unexpected Behavior:
Note that the "Event change" is not triggered during the page change to Page B.

Expected Behavior:
The "Event change" should be fired during the page change to Page B as configured in Google Tag Manager.

Next.js Version: 14.0.3